# Running and terminating an external process from Ruby

Tags: ruby, process

I want to run an external process under control of a Ruby (MRI) process.

Is there a way to start a long/infinite running job under Ruby, and then programmatically control its termination? I thought this would be relatively easy, but seem to be really struggling to figure out a way to do this.

Some example code, which *does not work*:

```
pid = fork { system "yes > /dev/null" }
sleep 1  # yes is happily running
Process.kill "TERM", pid
```

If I run this as a Ruby file, it runs happily. However, if I then `pgrep yes` I see that `yes` is still running. If I `pkill yes` it disappears successfully. The `KILL` signal is no more successful than the `TERM` signal.

How would I alter this code to run `yes` in the background but then allow its termination?

(In case it matters, which I doubt, this is with MRI Ruby 2.3 on macOS (haha) 10.11.)

Comment: strangely, removing the `sleep 1` changes the behavior and things appear correct with it missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea here but you're missing out on a subtle thing. Calling `fork` creates a child process, but `system` also does this as it's implemented as a `fork`/`exec` pair, so in effect you're killing the wrong process.

You can tell if you `puts pid` in there to see what process you're trying to kill. The one you're trying to kill will typically be the PID of the `yes` process that's actually running minus one.

What you probably want:

```
pid = fork do
  exec "/usr/bin/yes", out: File::NULL
end

sleep 1

Process.kill 'TERM', pid
```

You'll have to be very careful when using `exec` because at the slightest hint of something irregular then Ruby will create a shell process to execute your command which introduces yet another child process. Killing that won't actually kill the `yes` command. Here I've used the `out:` option to suppress `STDOUT` rather than leaning on the `> /dev/null` trick which automatically engages the shell wrapper.

In some quick testing I found that calling `exec 'yes'` caused an intermediate shell to be launched but specifying the full path avoided this.

Comment: thank you very much. this seems to fix it completely. I am starting to read up on the subtleties of exec.

Comment: Are there other avenues to explore? For example, a command that is less 'fragile' than `exec`, or a way to kill the first process and any other processes? Or a way to find the PID of the grandchild process?

Comment: `system`, `exec` and `spawn` are superficially similar but fundamentally different. They're all documented in [the `Kernel` section of the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html).

Comment: It depends on what this child process is doing. The `yes` here is a simple example, it's easy to call directly, but if you need to call a shell then you'll have to kill the entire process tree. There's [libraries that handle this better](https://github.com/jarib/childprocess) than what's in Ruby core if those are an option.